# can a 3D space be parallel/perpendicular to a plane or a line or another 3D space

Tags: geometry

As title. When I thought about parallel and perpendicular between line and line, plane and plane, line and plane, I want to go a step further find a 3D space having the relationships with another 3D space or a plane or a line. But I can't intuitively find an example by imagination. Tell me if the relationships are restricted in only 2D and 1D space, or they can be generalized into higher dimensions.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How many dimensions your vector space have? If it has two you can only find lines perpendicular to lines, if it has three you can find lines perpendicular to planes, if it has four you can find lines perpendicular to 3d subspaces and planes perpendicular to planes, if ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any $n$-dimensional space can be situated *parallel* to a given other $n$-dimensional space, simply by shifting it along a perpendicular line. This surely requires an embedding within an $(n+1)$-dimensional configuration space (in order to have an according perpendicular line).

Two $n$-dimensional spaces can be situated completely *perpendicular* to each other, when considering those within a $2n$-dimensional configuration space.

And, for sure, a point (i.e. a $0$-dimensional space) surely is always perpendicular to any $n$-dimensional space and this not even requires any larger embedding.

--- rk